# Tilapia - Growth on neck

Tags: health, fish, diseases

I have a tilapia, and recently it has developed a growth about `3/4 in.` in diameter, and about `2mm` tall on its neck.
The fish itself is about `8 in.` long, and is probably 9 months old.
I've looked all over the internet, but could not find anything like it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Growth as in hard tumor-like growth? Or some kind of fungus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fish, just like us, are subject to various forms of cancer and this sounds like an internal tumor manifesting externally on your fish. If it is a thyroid cancer, there is a possibility you can treat this with iodine in the water, otherwise it's inoperable. However, ideally you're able to consult with a vet to:

1. Confirm it is a cancer.
2. Confirm treatment possibilities, if any.

Now, I could be ***very wrong*** about this and I am ***not*** a vet, so this is ***not*** a diagnosis in any way. You can use Google image search for "[fish tumor](https://www.google.ca/search?q=fish%20tumor&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=X9swU6mUJ6WG0AGU1oGwBg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1912&bih=1179)" and see some images of growths and compare that to your fish to give you some idea. However, as I noted, the best option is a vet that knows fish illnesses, but that can be a challenge it is true.

Comment: @Jaxon - I'd prefer to be wrong about this, to be honest. Your description wasn't detailed, but it was the first thing I considered and it's not really that rare. :/

Comment: Not sure why your are assuming it is "inoperable", I know my exotics vet does tumor surgery on fish.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - Do you know that it successfully treated the cancer or just cosmetically removed the growth? What I've read is that it's you can't cure it through surgery.

Comment: Just like people it depends on the type and if it has spread.

Comment: Posted a related question http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2660