# Can cancer/growth surgery on fish be successful?

Tags: fish, surgery

This is a general question, on if cancer surgery on fish can be an effective treatment.  An [answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/tilapia-growth-on-neck/2659#2659) on the related question [Tilapia - Growth on neck](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2657) suggests that all cancer surgery on fish will be unsuccessful.

I personally have seen a large carp (*in a 5 gallon bucket of water*) with a tumor visiting my exotics vet for surgery.  I have another memory, of similar fish coming in for a check at another visit.  At the time I assumed that it was the same fish, coming in for a post surgery check up. I don't really know what the out come was, I have just assumed everything was fine.

**Update** (*some months later*) Sharing the waiting room, with two large white and orange/red carp again.  Owner verifies the carp is coming in for yet another cancer removal surgery, on a new tumor.  As we know some ornamental fish can [live long lives](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2784) and it appears survive repeated surgery.

Looking for documented results of surgery success rates for growths on fish, cancerous, non-cancerous or undefined.

Comment: Actually, I didn't say *all* since thyroid cancers are distinctly treatable with iodine. Tumor surgery for fish is out there, though most don't opt for it, but what doesn't seem to be described is *success* in remission.

Comment: @JohnCavan, I would not define drug treatment (iodine) as a "surgery". This question is focused on surgery not drugs ;)

Comment: Fair! Just want to be clear that I didn't think all were incurable. Still haven't found proof of success though, I suppose it's a bit of fringe activity for many given that few have emotional bonds with their fish.

Comment: I can't find anything right now (time) but look at zebrafish (danio rerio) and melanoma with the SETDB1 gene. There have been **lots** of studies and I'm sure some have involved surgical removal. That's scientific though, not hobbyist.

Comment: The lifespan on fish is so short and the cost for surgery so high, I doubt there's going to be many, if any, documented cases of tumor removal on fish.

Comment: @Jestep take a look at [Do some ornamental fish live 200 years?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2784)

Comment: Just ran upon this today: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/04/03/national-aquarium-tours_n_5083873.html?utm_hp_ref=green

Comment: no it will not be a successful surgery

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the surgery can be successful. If the tumour is not malignant and it is located in some easily operable place, for example on a fin, the surgery is easy and will be successful with a very high probability if done by a vet or even a skilled amateur. On the other hand, a malignant tumour already grown into some vitally important tissue may be inoperable. If any trace is left, it will grow again.

This is based on my 30-year experience of keeping and breeding tropical fish. If you want scientific articles, I bet there are many, but finding them might be a lot of work - here, for example, a koi healthy 15 months after a malignant tumour surgery: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f1de/fb2d1effea3e64506b0e65dd8d6b28349507.pdf

Comment: The answer does not really provided anything not in the question.  Can you improve it by adding documented outcomes?

Comment: What do you consider a "documented outcome"? This is based on my 30-year experience of keeping and breeding tropical fish. If you want scientific articles, I bet there are many, but finding them might be a lot of work - here, for example, a koi healthy 15 months after a malignant tumour surgery: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f1de/fb2d1effea3e64506b0e65dd8d6b28349507.pdf

Comment: for this sugery to be  considered a sucsess i think the malignant growth must be gone for atleast two years like it is in humans.